# Poincaré–Bendixson theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Does someone know a good reference for a proof of the Poincaré–Bendixson theorem using the language of vector fields?

Answer (score 2):

If you read French you can look at this one, which is really nice :

Serge Cantat, *Théorème de Poincaré-Bendixson,* Le journal de maths des élèves, ENS Lyon, vol. 1, no 3,‎ 1995; [http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~benzoni/CantatJME3.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ebenzoni/CantatJME3.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20061120101051/http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ebenzoni/CantatJME3.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

Look at Hirsch-Smale (or, I presume, Hirsch-Smale-Devaney) *Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, ...*

Comment: the original hirsh-smale is a wonderful text. harsh-smale-devaney is pretty useless compared to the original.

Comment: I haven't looked at it, @abel. But, as a rule of thumb, most books get worse with subsequent editions and the addition of coauthors.